# Plotting few lines using one matrix

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

Let's say I have two matrices x and y

x = [1 2 3 1 2]
y = [1 2 3 1 3]

I want to plot two lines from it, first three points and then two last points.

In the end I want to get this plot. Can I do it with Matlab?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) indexing to specify pairs of coordinate vectors input arguments for `plot`:

```
plot(x(1:3), y(1:3), x(4:5), y(4:5))
```

Answer (score 1):

use `hold all` to plot several lines on the same axis.

```
figure
plot( x(1:3), y(1:3) );
hold all;
plot( x(4:end), y(4:end) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
plot(x(1:3),y(1:3),'b',x(4:end),y(4:end),'r')
```